# Can not assign to immutable expression in Swift Tuple?

Tags: swift

```
class Object {
    var a : Int?
    var b : Int?
}

func swap(_ obj: Object?) -> Object? {
//    guard let obj = obj else {
//        return nil
//    }
//    (obj.a,obj.b) = (obj.b,obj.a)
//

//    It's ok of course
//    var tmp = obj?.a
//    obj?.a = obj?.b
//    obj?.b = tmp

//    Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Int?'  
    (obj?.a,obj?.b) = (obj?.b,obj?.a)
    return obj
}
```

`guard` has an implicitly unwrapped,so the code above is ok.

But why the code below can not compile?

Comment: Hmm, it seems like optional chaining on the LHS of assignment is handled as a special case, rather than a productive construct (pardon the linguistics term). `(obj?.a,obj?.b) = (a, b)` doesn't work for the same reason that `(1 + 1, 2 + 2) = (a, b)` doesn't work - the LHS are mere _expressions_, rather than "l-values". I can't find any documentations to support my claims though...

Comment: Even if this would compile: It mutates the passed-in object *and* returns it, which is a bit unusual.